# EF table.A != Table.B || Table.A != Table.C

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a simple need from my EF

```
.Where(x=> x.A!= x.B || x.A != x.C)
```

This produces a SQL which looks like below.

```
(( NOT (([Extent1].[A] = [Extent1].[B]) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[A] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[B] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) OR ( NOT (([Extent1].[A] = [Extent1].[C]) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[A] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[C] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))))
```

All I want is a Sql which is similar to this.

```
(( [Extent1].A <> [Extent1].B )OR ([Extent1].A <> [Extent1].C ))
```

It is a string column I am comparing.

My intent in Sql works fine but the intent of me doing the same in EF is not yielding the same result.

Its all to do with the Null columns.

Comment: Try using .Equals instead (not sure about it). x=> !x.A.Equals(x.B)...

Comment: @Thomas No  I did mean an OR condition.

Comment: @Santhos Tried no difference it evaluates to the same Sql expression.

Comment: @Thomas I see that the case when Null is getting expressed by the EF whilest it prepares its query. But where as I don't want it to do.  Its how EF treating nulls, vs how SQL treats null.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://henrylu.me/2014/07/05/null-value-handling-in-entity-framework/) would help

Comment: @bhushanvinay it was worth a shot. I usually use database Views when I want a really specific logic. (Even though this does not seem too specific.)

Comment: @Thomas you are the man. you got it right setting the Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true; works like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended [here](http://henrylu.me/2014/07/05/null-value-handling-in-entity-framework/), you should set `Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `true`.